# How to combine layers with lots of objects that have alpha textures?

Tags: render-layers

So here is the problem.

I have 1 layer with lots of objects with alpha textures and another layer with 1 solid object, positioned to appear somewhere in the middle of those alpha-textured. I have animated my camera to fly through the alpha-textured objects and copied it to both layers. Then tried to composite it in all the ways I found but it doesn't work. I think, the problem is that my layer with alpha-textured objects is treated like a whole by a compositor and as a whole it does not have any alpha, because there are so many objects that together they are overlapping till no visible transparency left. Alphaover, z-combine and 2 z-combine(with 1 inverted) don't work.

I'm trying to fly with camera and to see my shiny object through those alpha-textured objects. If I put it in the same layer it works perfectly but then I can't add effects to an object.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a few images to your post that illustrate the issue, and also an image of your compositing nodes. Or even better would be to look at your blend file

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have done it, now I don't have an access to a blend file but if nobody will answer I will update my question with all the info later on.